# Node JS | [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema

**stock.js**

```
const stk = require('../models/stock');
const math = require('mathjs');
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');

exports.getStock = (req,res,next)=>
{     
    stk.find().exec().then(result=>{
        res.status(200).json(result);
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(err=>{
        res.status(404).json({message : 'something went wrong'});
        console.log(err);
    });
}
exports.createStock = (req,res,next)=>{         
        const stock = new stk({
            category  : req.body.category,
            product : req.body.product,
            brand  : req.body.brand,
            quantity : req.body.quantity            
        });
        stock.save().then(result =>{
            res.status(200).json(result);
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(err =>{
            res.status(404).json(err);
            console.log(err);
        });
}

exports.updateStock = (req,res,next)=>
{
    console.log('updated');   
}

exports.deleteStock = (req,res,next)=>{
 console.log('deleted');    
}
```

**my model file is**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const stockSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    barcode : {type : Number , required : true,unique : true},
    category : {type : String, required : true},
    product : {type : String, required : true},
    brand : {type : String, required : true},
    quantity : {type : Number, required : true}
});

module.exports =  mongoose.model('stock',stockSchema);
```

and **router.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const stock = require('../controller/stock');

router.get('/',stock.getStock);

router.post('/',stock.createStock);

router.patch('/:barcode',stock.updateStock);

router.delete('/:barcode',stock.deleteStock);

module.exports = router;
```

**Error Stack:**

```
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined
    at exports.createStock (C:\Users\kapil choudhary\small projects\barcodeDemo\api\controller\stock.js:18:34)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\kapil choudhary\small projects\barcodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\kapil choudhary\small projects\barcodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\kapil choudhary\small projects\barcodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\kapil choudhary\small projects\barcodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\kapil choudhary\small projects\barcodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\kapil choudhary\small projects\barcodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12) 
    at next (C:\Users\kapil choudhary\small projects\barcodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\kapil choudhary\small projects\barcodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\kapil choudhary\small projects\barcodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\kapil choudhary\small projects\barcodeDemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: are you using any parsing middleware?

Comment: share you main file's code

Comment: it's solved by using new tab in postman